# Перенаправлять все запросы на index.php

Tags: .htaccess, access

1. Необходимо, чтобы абсолютно все запросы поступали на обработку в index.php таким образом, чтобы, например, запрос вида example.com/* (просто добавляем звездочку) также направлялся в index.php, а не выводил Access Forbidden.
2. Если есть совпадение с названием папки или файла, тогда выполнять запрос без index.php

Answer (score 4):

В `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

Comment: этот вариант не обрабатывает звездочку в запросе, выдает access forbidden. example.com/* - ошибка, а если example.com/123/* - все норм

Comment: Использую OpenServer (Apache 2.4). Возможно там что-то нужно править. Проверил на тестовом серваке beget.ru - там со звездочкой все норм, а вот на локальном не могу с ней справиться

Comment: @Bogdanfar, 1. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28493371/4827341 2. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/15884