# Перенаправлять все сегменты URL на index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Допустим есть ссылки вида site.ru/news1, site.ru/article1 и т.д.

Как настроить htaccess или index.php так, чтобы при значение первого сегмента URL - все перенаправлялось на index.php, где уже будет обработка?

Comment: Забыл добавить, ссылки идут вида site.ru/page/news1, site.ru/page/article1 и т.д. index.php находится в папке page

Comment: 1)https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/543447/ 2)https://stackoverflow.com/q/18406156 3)https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=265730#answers_list_answer 4)https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767447 5)https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=305

Answer (score 1):

Понял как:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page/index.php
```